# what can't take a vector of strings and replace a character of any string with the offest and assigmnet operators?

Tags: c++, string, containers, vectorization

I'm trying to search a vector of strings and replace any punctuation with a space.
The compiler won't allow it with [][] and =. 
Is there a way to do it?
If not, what string member function and parameters would I need? eg. string.replace(?,?,?);

```
  void evaluate_char(vector<string> & x)
    {
    string space = " ";//can I us a variable space in stead? seems not.

    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0;  j < x[i].size(); ++j)
            {
            if(ispunct(x[i][j]))
                x[i][j] = " ";//says something like not allowed to const char to char

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the space *character* as opposed to a string containing a single space:

```
            x[i][j] = ' ';
```

Notice the single quotes instead of double quotes.  Double quotes indicates a string literal, while single quotes indicate a character literal.

Because you want a single character, you need the latter.

Also, you do not need `string space = " ";`  You can safely delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

A string consists of characters. So you need to assign  `' '` (character literal) instead of `" "` which is a string literal and of type `const char*` to `x[i][j]`.

You can also use `std::replace_if` in this case and generalize your approach a little:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template<class UnaryPredicate>
void replace_in_string_vector (std::vector<string> & string_vector, UnaryPredicate P, char const new_val)
{
  for (auto & the_string : string_vector)
  {
    std::replace_if(the_string.begin(), the_string.end(), P, new_val);
  }
}
```

Usable like this:

```
replace_in_string_vector(my_vector, ispunct, ' ');
```

(This can -of course- also be done in an even more general fashion. Also note that the for loop using the auto keyword requires a C++11 compiler.)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a string literal for the replacement, but you want a character literal instead, which is written with a single quote instead of a double quote.

```
x[i][j] = ' ';
```

That being said, why don't you use `std::replace_if` to replace characters in the string `x[i]`?

```
replace_if(begin(x[i]), end(x[i]), &::ispunct, ' ');
```

Also, since C++11, there is the very easy range-based for loop. Your code can then become as easy as this:

```
for (auto &s : x)
    replace_if(begin(s), end(s), &::ispunct, ' ');
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/U1Nj1z